# PHP execute a php script on one server with a script located on a second server and insert data in a db located on a third server

Tags: php

I have three servers, and i would like to know if it's possible(and how :-s) to basically `query` the database from server 1 using a `php` script on server 2 and then insert that data on server 3:

```
Server-1: db - that has the data
Server-2: get data from Server-1 db and insert it into Server-3 db
Server-3: db - that will have the data
```

I can mention that i can't connect to `mysql` from Server 1 to server 2.

Thank you for taking time to read & answer to my question! :D

Comment: Hi Emma! This question is far too broad in its current form and is better suited to a forum or subreddit. SO is designed for specific programming problems in Q&A format. I'm flagging to close this question. I recommend attempting some code and ask a question when you run into a problem you can't solve.

Comment: Oky @JamesJones, sorry! :-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple,

Use API concept,

Write a script on Server 1, which will get the data, then call it from Server 2.
On Server 3, write a script that will insert the data to its database, and call it from Server 2.

lets say the server names are Server1, Server2 and Server3

Lets Say for example you want to get the users from Server 1 and save them to Server 3, what you will go is the following:

- Write a PHP file called getUsers.php which will get all the users
  from Server 1 DB and return them as JSON.
- On Server 2, you will call that file using the link
  `http:\\Server1\getUsers.php`, which will return all Users you have
  in JSON format.
- Now on Server 3, you will need to write PHP file that stores these
  users to its Database, let's name it saveUsers.php
- Now from Server2, you will need to submit the users you got from
  server 1 to server 3, you will have to submit them using PHP CURL to
  the link `http:\\server3\saveUsers.php`

Once all these steps are done, now you have your Own API,
But please put in your mind you are just scratching the surface of API, what I provided here is common and simple way to have it.

This way you can achieve what you want.

Comment: Hey @RayA , i'm not really familiar with the concept of API but i took it to google and...is a REST php API the API you're talking about?

Comment: I'll edit my answer, it will help you understand better

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me!!:D

Comment: Oky, so i was reading some REST API tutorials and after 15 minutes i've got my first query all the way trough from server 1 to server 3 <3! Thank youuuuuuuuuuu! :D <3 <3 <3

Comment: you're welcome, if you wish to mark my answer as accepted, please do!

Comment: Of course i'm going to, you just made my day <3 i was thinking the whole day about how could this be done but i couldn't figure it out :D

Comment: Glad I helped, if you need anything more, please do feel free to ask :) happy coding!

Comment: Thank you!!! You too! :D